# Using PHP imap to move AND clear \\Seen. Either works, both doesn't

Tags: php, imap

Ok, I give. It's time to ask for help.

I need to use imap_mail_move or imap_mail_copy to move the current email to another folder AND mark it as unread. The documentation is lacking and I can't seen to find an example of both of these functions in conjunction.

```
imap_mail_move($inbox, $uniqueID, 'to_be_processed', CP_UID);
imap_clearflag_full($inbox, imap_uid($inbox, $uniqueID), '\\Seen', ST_UID);
```

I do expunge at the end. Everything works EXCEPT the unread part. Once I move it, I think the ID changes?

If I get this to work, I hope you'll help me understand WHY? One question I have is at what point is a message marked read?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers or https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer if you found your own answer

Answer (score 2):

IMAP only works on a folder-by-folder basis.  Once you move the message, it’s no longer in the folder you’re processing, so you can’t manipulate the message anymore*.  Therefore, you need to make changes to the message *before* you move it.  Just reverse your commands:

```
imap_clearflag_full($inbox, $uniqueID, '\\Seen', ST_UID);
imap_mail_move($inbox, $uniqueID, 'to_be_processed', CP_UID);
```

Also, don’t call imap_uid() on something that is already a UID.

*: Technically, a \Deleted copy may remain in the source folder, and you’re manipulating that, not the message that has moved.